# Global Variables JS - Component Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

So I have a global variable defined in my code and it is throwing an error. The error is

> Failed to save undefined: 0Ad1F0000000meq:
>   org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException:
>   Only functions are allowed in javascript controllers [3, 17]: '10':
>   Source

My code is in JavaScript. It is a controller for my component. I want to declare a global variable but am I declaring it correctly?

Simplified code:

```
({
  x: 10,   /* Global variable */
  y: 15    /* Global variable */

  function1 : function(..){
  },
  ....
})
```

Comment: you cannot do this as you are attempting it in your lightning controller, the message is pretty straightforward : Only functions are allowed in javascript controllers. have you gone through the documentation by any chance? or do you have a reference that states that this should work?

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation now.

Comment: :thumbsup: the trailheads on building lightnign components should give you a global understanding of how the aura framework and lightning work to help you develop

Comment: @Mguy, my answer is incorrect, please mark the other answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can declare those variables in helper and access them like that:

```
({
    x: 10,
    y: 15,
    someHelperFunction: function() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
})
```

or from the controller:

```
({
    someControllerFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(helper.x);
    }
})
```